# Image preview not showing on add/edit page

Tags: 8, media

Preview of the uploaded images are not showing on the node add/edit page but images are uploaded correctly. We're using Lightning Acquia distribution and using Entity browser for the image field.

What could be the possible issue?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `What could be the possible issue?` The /sites/default/files folder may not have the required permissions to create new files. Thus, the thumbnails which are image styles cannot be created.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in the current version of entity_browser that ships with Lightning.  Upgrade the entity_browser module to 8.x-1.0-alpha10 or later to resolve the issue.

If you have used composer to install, simply update the drupal/entity_browser module via composer.